# Mysql to Linq query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

MySQL Query

```
select MAX(os.aggregate_date) as lastMonthDay,os.totalYTD
  from (SELECT aggregate_date,Sum(YTD) AS totalYTD 
        FROM tbl_aggregated_tables
          WHERE subscription_type = 'Subcription Income'
        GROUP BY aggregate_date) as os
GROUP by MONTH(os.aggregate_date),YEAR(os.aggregate_date)
ORDER BY lastMonthDay;
```

converted to this LINQ query

```
var income = context.tbl_aggregated_tables
                   .Where(s => s.subscription_type == "Subcription Income")
                   .GroupBy(s => s.aggregate_date)
                   .Select(result => new
                   {
                       date = result.Key,
                       ytdsum = result.Select(x => x.YTD).Sum()
                   })
                   .GroupBy(s => new { month = s.date.Month, year = s.date.Year })
                   .Select(
                    // select max data and take its ytdsum value 
                        ).ToList();
```

The purpose of second grouping is to find the max day of each month with a year.
Now, How to select the max date of each month and its ytdsum after the second Grouping?

**update**

```
income = context.tbl_aggregated_tables
                   .Where(s => s.subscription_type == "Subcription Income")
                   .GroupBy(s => s.aggregate_date)
                   .Select(result => new
                   {
                       date = result.Key,
                       ytdsum = result.Select(x => x.YTD).Sum()
                   })
                   .GroupBy(s => new { s.date.Month, s.date.Year })
                   .Select(
                     x => x.Max(s => s.date)
                   ).ToList()
```

this way it's only return the dates and i could not return the full object of the list including ytdSum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked good but it takes much more time than the original mysql query.

```
 var income = context.tbl_aggregated_tables
                       .Where(s => s.subscription_type == "Subcription Income"
                        )
                       .GroupBy(s => s.aggregate_date)
                       .Select(result => new
                       {
                           date = result.Key,
                           ytdsum = result.Select(x => x.YTD).Sum()
                       })
                       .GroupBy(s => new { s.date.Month, s.date.Year })
                       .Select(
                         x => x.OrderByDescending(s => s.date)
                       )
                       .ToList()
                       .Select(el => el.FirstOrDefault())
                       .OrderBy(s=>s.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var income = context.tbl_aggregated_tables
                   .Where(s => s.subscription_type == "Subcription Income")
                   .GroupBy(s => s.aggregate_date)
                   .Select(result => new
                   {
                       date = result.Key,
                       ytdsum = result.Select(x => x.YTD).Sum()
                   })
                   .GroupBy(s => new { month = s.date.Month, year = s.date.Year })
                   .Select(
                        x => x.OrderByDescending(k => k.date).First() 
                   ).ToList();
```

`income` now is a list of objects, each of them have `date` and `ytdsum`

Comment: it throws an exception and once the last select eliminated it works fine

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: first i received an exception message says " The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead" --- first() replaced with FirstOrDefault() an exception is thrown again with `
exceptionMessage "Unknown column 'Distinct2.C1' in 'where clause'"
exceptionType "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException"
stackTrace "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)\r\n .....`